# Method returning true instead of false for certain arguments

Tags: ruby

Hi I have a method XO which

- returns **true** if a string has the same amount of 'x's and 'o's
- returns **false** if there are more x's than o's and vice versa
- returns ***true*** when NO x's and o's are present.

These should be the correct tests:

```
XO("ooxx") => true
XO("xooxx") => false
XO("ooxXm") => true
XO("zpzpzpp") => true // when no 'x' and 'o' is present should return true
XO("zzoo") => false
```

For some reason, my method is always returning true and I don't understand why.

```
def XO(str)
   x = str.count("o" "O") 
   y = str.count ("x" "X")
    if x == y
     true
    elsif
     str.split.select { |x| !x.include?("o" "O") && !x.include?("x" "X") }
     true
    else
     false
    end
end
```

I am a novice to ruby so apologies for my shabby code.

Comment: Can you tell me the reason for marking down my post? I have rightly attempted the problem and correctly posted here.

Comment: I think your question is fine (I'm working on it right now). Someone must have gotten trigger-happy with the downvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is that this line:

```
str.split.select { |x| !x.include?("o" "O") && !x.include?("x" "X") }
```

will return an empty array `[]` in a situation where the string has no 'x's or 'o's. In Ruby, any array is considered truthy, even an empty one. So your code is always returning `true` here. You can fix it by checking that the array is empty:

```
def XO(str)
   x = str.count("o" "O") 
   y = str.count ("x" "X")
    if x == y
     true
    elsif
     str.split.select { |x| !x.include?("o" "O") && !x.include?("x" "X") }.empty?
     true
    else
     false
    end
end
```

This code will run fine and do what you want. However, it is overly complicated! If you look at your requirements:

- returns true if a string has the same amount of 'x's and 'o's
- returns false if there are more x's than o's and vice versa
- returns true when NO x's and o's are present.

When there are no x's and no o's, you could say there are in fact 0 x's and 0 o's, which means there is the *same amount* of 'x's and 'o's. Which means you can just do this:

```
def XO(str)
   x = str.count("o" "O") 
   y = str.count ("x" "X")
   x == y
end
```

In situations where there aren't any 'x's or 'o's, you'll have `0 == 0` which returns true, just like you want.

Answer (score 2):

A straight-up equivalence test will meet all your conditions.

```
def xo str
  str.count("oO") == str.count("xX")
end

xo "ooxx"    #=> true
xo "xooxx"   #=> false
xo "ooxXm"   #=> true
xo "zpzpzpp" #=> true
xo "zzoo"    #=> false
```

Use two spaces for indentation and lowercase for method names. Notice the more compact `count` argument.

Comment: Appreciate a solution. However, why wasn't my method passing?